# integrating JaCoCo in sonar using Ant

Tags: ant, sonarqube, jacoco

I am stuck integrating JaCoCo with sonar using Ant.
Very new to this task, and integrating for the first time.
I have gone through many links like

- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/projects/code-coverage/ut/ant/ut-ant-jacoco-runTests/build.xml
- http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project
- and many more.

I am trying to display result on another VM, and code is in my VM.
Getting all sorts of errors related to JDK6,VM, and not able to analyze my package structure
My que is do I need to define any specific project properties beside given in the above links for VM etc
I would also like to include that my checkstyle, and findbugs is working like charm.
Only need to integrate JaCoCo.
Any information will be of great help.

If found my description is not up to my mark, kindly ask

Thanks for help

Comment: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/it/ant/it-jacoco-ant

Comment: Thanks Mark, I would like to tell you this is the same link of github which I mentioned in my que.

Answer (score 9):

The following is an ANT build that is configured to run a junit unit test and use jacoco for code coverage reporting. The results are uploaded to Sonar and finally ivy is used to download 3rd party jars and manage classpaths.

## Example

```
├── build.properties
├── build.xml
├── ivy.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── org
    │           └── demo
    │               └── App.java
    └── test
        └── java
            └── org
                └── demo
                    └── AppTest.java
```

### build.properties

```
# Build properties
build.dir=build

src.dir=src/main/java
test.src.dir=src/test/java

classes.dir=${build.dir}/classes
test.classes.dir=${build.dir}/test-classes

reports.dir=${build.dir}/reports

# Sonar properties
sonar.projectKey=org.demo:demo
sonar.projectName=Demo project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.projectDescription=This is my demo Sonar project

sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

sonar.working.directory=${build.dir}/sonar

sonar.language=java
sonar.sources=${src.dir}
sonar.binaries=${classes.dir}
sonar.tests=${test.src.dir}

sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.surefire.reportsPath=${reports.dir}/junit
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=${build.dir}/jacoco.exec
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="test" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <target name="bootstrap" description="Install ivy">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar"/>
    </target>

    <target name="resolve" description="Download dependencies and setup classpaths">
        <ivy:resolve/>
        <ivy:report todir='${reports.dir}/ivy' graph='false' xml='false'/>

        <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="test.path"    conf="test"/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path"   conf="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="init" depends="resolve" description="Create build directories">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${test.classes.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}/junit"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compile source code">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false" debug="true" classpathref="compile.path"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile-tests" depends="compile" description="Compile test source code">
        <javac srcdir="${test.src.dir}" destdir="${test.classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false" debug="true">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="test.path"/>
                <pathelement path="${classes.dir}"/>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="test" depends="compile-tests" description="Run unit tests and code coverage reporting">
        <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml" classpathref="build.path"/>

        <jacoco:coverage destfile="${build.dir}/jacoco.exec" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
            <junit haltonfailure="yes" fork="true">
                <classpath>
                    <path refid="test.path"/>
                    <pathelement path="${classes.dir}"/>
                    <pathelement path="${test.classes.dir}"/>
                </classpath>
                <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
                <formatter type="xml"/>
                <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.dir}/junit">
                    <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}">
                        <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
                        <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
                    </fileset>
                </batchtest>
            </junit>
        </jacoco:coverage>
    </target>

    <target name="sonar" depends="test" description="Upload metrics to Sonar">
        <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml" classpathref="build.path"/>

        <ivy:cachepath pathid="sonar.libraries" conf="compile"/> 

        <sonar:sonar xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleanup build files">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations defaultconfmapping="compile->default">
        <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
        <conf name="test"    description="Required for test only" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="build"   description="Build dependencies"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- compile dependencies -->

        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.10" conf="test->default"/>

        <!-- build dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.codehaus.sonar-plugins" name="sonar-ant-task" rev="2.1" conf="build->default"/>
        <dependency org="org.jacoco" name="org.jacoco.ant" rev="0.6.3.201306030806" conf="build->default"/>

        <!-- Global exclusions -->
        <exclude org="org.apache.ant"/>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Comment: Some working sample code: http://itestfirst.wordpress.com/2014/10/15/ant-sonar-and-jacoco-working-example/