# How to use XX Splitverifier in ANT?

Tags: ant, code-coverage

I have a quick question. Looking for some help.

I am doing code coverage for my simple java file using emma. I am stuck up at the point of running the instrumented class file. I am doing this all from ANT build.xml file. When I try to run this instrumented class file, I get the below error:

[java] java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 11

Please let me know if you want my entire build.xml. Will be happy to share.

From forums, I see we can use XX Splitverifier. I don't know how to use this in ANT build.xml file. Can anyone please share your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good explanation of this problem here:

- [Understanding subtle new behaviours of JDK 7](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/fabriziogiudici/archive/2012/05/07/understanding-subtle-new-behaviours-jdk-7)

> Problems actually arise if you're using bytecode manipulating tools, such as AspectJ in static weaving mode - I do - that haven't been updated yet. They basically read the bytecode, tagged as Java 7 bytecode, and perform changes in Java 6 mode, saving the results still tagged in Java 7 mode. Thus, the VM in JDK 7 sees Java 7 bytecode and activates the new Java 7 verifier, which fails (or can fail) when it meet the bytecode manipulated in Java 6 mode.
>
> It seems complicated, but the simple solution is to force the use of the old verifier in JDK 7 by adding this VM runtime option: -XX:-UseSplitVerifier.

So this is a backward compatibility problem. You're faced with a choice of applying the work-around or changing your code coverage tool.

Do you have a strong reason to use Emma? Jacoco has emerged as its [replacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Code_Coverage_Tools). I would also recommend using [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/), which will additionally integrate Findbugs, PMD and Checkstyle into your build process. For an example on how this all works in ANT see the following answer:

- [integrating JaCoCo in sonar using Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382287/integrating-jacoco-in-sonar-using-ant/20413444#20413444)