# Configure project name and version for sonar at jenkins in an ant project

Tags: ant, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a problem with the configuration in an ant project at jenkins with sonar. For to establish a ant project with sonar at Jenkins it's necessary to indicate the properties: *sonar.projectVersion*, *sonar.projectName*, *sonar.projectKeys*, *sonar.binaries*, *sonar.libraries* and *sonar.sources*. I would like knowing if it's possible to establish the projectVersion and projectName in the file *build.xml* or *build.properties* and to indicate in the sonar that it takes the value of these properties. For example:

- build.properties (or build.xml):
  project.name=XXX-XXX-XXX
  project.version=2.0.3
- Sonar configuration at Jenkins:
  sonar.projectName=${project.name}
  sonar.projectVersion=${project.version}

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: See an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382287/integrating-jacoco-in-sonar-using-ant/20413444#20413444 Shows Sonar settings being imported from a build properties file. Beware it uses ivy to manage the "sonar.libraries" path, I find this very useful in complex projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible yet, but feel free to vote for https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARUNNER-76