# How can I add JaCoCoverage to my Ant build process?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build, code-coverage

I have a Java project in NetBeans 7.4.  If I want to run a code coverage report using JaCoCoverage, I can right click on the project name and then select `Test with JaCoCoverage` from the context menu.

I want to trigger this same process from my Ant `build.xml` file.  Can I add an Ant command to make this happen?  If so, can I direct the resulting report to the directory of my choice?

Something like this maybe...

```
<target name="-post-jar">
  <!-- run JaCoCoverage here...-->
  <exec executable="JaCoCoverage"/>
</target>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382287/integrating-jacoco-in-sonar-using-ant/20413444#20413444

Answer (score 0):

JaCoCo has a set of Ant tasks that make this straightforward.  See the [documentation](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html).