# Adding JaCoCo to Ivy?

Tags: java, ant, ivy, jacoco

I have tried to find the right `org="..` address for JaCoCo so that I can simply add the address to my ivy.xml file and it will take care of the dependency.

But I have trouble finding the right link and was wondering if anyone knew what it was?

I am going to use `Ant` to build my project, so I'd have to put JaCoCo to use in there.

None of the below are correct:

```
<!-- JaCoCo -->
<dependency org="org.jacoco.agent" name="jacoco-agent" rev="0.6.2.2" />
<dependency org="org.jacoco.core" name="jacoco-core" rev="0.6.2.2" />
<dependency org="org.jacoco.report" name="jacoco-report" rev="0.6.2.2" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll only need a single dependency declaration:

```
<dependency org="org.jacoco" name="org.jacoco.ant" rev="0.7.2.201409121644" />
```

The "core", "agent" and "report" jars get pulled in as dependencies.

- [Jacoco ANT task jar in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jacoco%7Corg.jacoco.ant%7C0.7.2.201409121644%7Cjar)

The following is an build example that uses ivy to manage Jacoco and Sonar plugins. It's worth noting how it uses a "build" configuration mapping to create a classpath for just the ANT task jars.

- [integrating JaCoCo in sonar using Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382287/integrating-jacoco-in-sonar-using-ant/20413444#20413444)

Answer (score 2):

I use following dependencies:

```
<dependency org="org.jacoco" name="org.jacoco.ant"    rev="0.6.3.201306030806"/>
<dependency org="org.jacoco" name="org.jacoco.core"   rev="0.6.3.201306030806"/>
<dependency org="org.jacoco" name="org.jacoco.agent"  rev="0.6.3.201306030806"/>
<dependency org="org.jacoco" name="org.jacoco.report" rev="0.6.3.201306030806"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try them out when I can tomorrow and get back to you!

Comment: I used the solution from Mark O'Connor as the ant build includes the others