# Sonarqube on Jenkins with IVY project

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, ivy, sonarqube-scan

I have a ivy project setup in jenkins, on which I like to run sonarqube analysis.

Unfortunately it is not possible (it seems) to add the sonarqube analysis on the project itself, but I need to create a mirror project (free-style) with sonarqube scanner as only build step.

I also need to set then the basedir not to the mirror project, but to the original one.

All this is a bit unfortunate and I was wondering whether there is another option to run a sonar analysis on an ivy project in jenkins ?

I have Jenkins 2.7.4, Sonarqube plugin 2.4.4

Comment: An old example. Might still be working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382287/integrating-jacoco-in-sonar-using-ant/20413444#20413444

Comment: thanks for the link, but this includes actively changing the original build files, which I like to avoid. My hope was to simply add the sonar build step from jenkins to the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve my goal with using the PostBuildAction plugin.

This allowed to add the sonarqube-scanner job to be added at the end of the run.